# Transforming a a string ID into numeric and then joining into a large dataset without consuming all memory

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm transforming a set of distinct `id_product` (string with letters and numbers) into a numeric id (its own row number in this case) and then joining this new numeric column into a large dataset with multiple IDs, as it follows:

```
with cte as (select distinct id_product,
                    row_number() over () as id_product2
             from tb_market_data
select t1.id_customer,
       t1.id_product,
       t2.id_product2
from tb_market_data as t1
left join cte as t2 on t1.id_product = t2.id_product
```

Although this method works, since I have a large dataset, joining those two tables using a string as a key is consuming all memory.
There's a way to make the processing less memory hunger?

PS: I can't simple remove all the letters from `id_product` because the lack off then would result into two different products being the same (e.g. X001 and B001 would be equally 001)

Comment: Why you are using WITH clause even? Simply use ROW_NUMBER() in you query.

Comment: It seems in your use case the numbers are assigned in a non-deterministic way, since there's no `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the logic to assign the new ID is not deterministic you have freedom to assign it in any way.

You can use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` for this purpose and avoid the join.

For example:

```
select
  id_customer,
  id_product,
  dense_rank() over(order by id_product) as id_product2
from tb_market_data
```

In terms of performance, this can made faster if there was an index by `id_product` and if the query sorted by this column.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm! I wasn't familiar with `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`